# Node redis createClient throws net.isIP not a function error

Tags: redis

```
const redis = require("redis");
redis.createClient();
```

I have the above simple code, but it always threw error saying net.isIP is not a function.
I searched and tried several different ways but couldn't get passed this error.

Any pointers? Thanks.
Node version 15.8.0

Answer (score 0):

change line 3 in redis index.js file of module to `var net = require('net-browserify')` and

```
npm i net-browserify
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I was trying to use it in a react app that runs on the browser which I found out that I wasn't supposed to.